trouble upgrading docker compose with choco
I installed docker desktop using choco install docker-desktop --version=2.0.0.3
I have to use 2.0.0.3 because it is the last supported version for my version of Windows.
Per Docker Desktop, this installed:
Docker-Engine: 18.09.2
Docker-Compose: 1.23.2
I don't want to use compose version 1, so I see that I can use up to docker-compose 3.7 from their compatibility tables with Docker-Engine: 18.06.0+
So I tried to update docker-compose with:
choco install docker-compose --version=2.26.0 (2.26 because Chocolatey didn't seem to have compose version 3)
The installation completed successfully but docker-compose --version still shows 1.23.2. I don't see any new compose binary added to the path. Also I have no idea where Chocolatey installed it. How can I fix this? I would try to add compose to the path manually but I can't figure out where Chocolatey installed it.

What is  where docker-compose output?

Chocolatey CLI runs the installer. So wherever the installer normally puts it is where it will be.

@MonsieurMerso where docker-compose shows C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-compose.exe but this is the 1.23.2 version.

The documentation for the package in chocolatey states this:

To use Compose V2 through Docker type docker compose

So, docker compose as opposed to the standalone docker-compose.
As mentioned int the Migrate to Compose V2, compose is no longer a standalone binary, but depends on the docker client.
Sure, there's this mention:

Additionally, the Use Compose V2 setting is turned on by default, which provides an alias from docker-compose.

but that might not be on by default when you upgrade your installation like that.
You can also run docker system info to check the integrated compose version. The output should have something like this included:
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.13.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.25.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose



docker compose
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.

Also the only thing mentioned under plugins is volume, network, and log.
